# Null pointer exception outside my code

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I get Null Pointer Exception at open ListActivity in my code but all trace is not my code.

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2606)  at
>   android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)    at
>   android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:681)   at
>   android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:742)    at
>   android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1661)    at
>   android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2427)    at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14938)     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)    at
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1021)  at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14938)     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)    at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)     at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14938)     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)    at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)     at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14938)     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1694)     at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1552)    at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)  at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14938)     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)    at
>   android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)     at
>   android.view.View.layout(View.java:14938)     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4601)    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2212)   at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2026)
>     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1236)    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5160)
>     at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
>     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)   at
>   android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)    at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
>     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)   at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

How I can know where the error occurs?

Comment: can you post the offending code?

Comment: Code is a litte bit complex, the list activity is >1000 lines and this error occurs only in some devices. I need to know how detect the bug, not post full code because is very complex.

Comment: can you reproduce the error while debugging and isolate the line?

Comment: No because I get error from remote log, in my device I can´t reproduce this error.

Comment: Could you post devices names and Android versions where this occurs?

Comment: Device: 4.2.2 samsung GT-I8200L.

Comment: Are you creating any custom adapter class ?  is the adapter class still big to post here ?  This crash is likely to come from adapter class.

Comment: Specifically, you are returning `null` from your `getView` method of your `Adapter`, posting your adapter code will help people figure out why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @iagreen said, "Specifically, you are returning null from your getView method of your Adapter".

I was returning null in some case in custom adapter in getWiew.